# what is the name and how to implement it in android tablet?

Tags: android

[image]

Does anybody know what is the name of upper part of this image(Buddies,activity,chat,history) which is like tab and also how to implement it in android tablet?

Comment: "which is like tab!"- why you doubt? And What does it make  difference to develope for tablet or other device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the TabHost: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Here's a good example of how to use it: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 0):

This is tabs. Before honeycombs tabs were done using the TabActivity + Activity group. But now the activity group class is deprecated and fragments should be used instead.